# Viewing a 30+ columns table in JasperViewer

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a table with 2 rows and 40 columns ,i need present it in a readable format.Presently i have not set column width in the column builder  so it is displayed as very narrow columns and is unreadable.
I was exploring these possibilites:

```
1. introducing a scrollbar and how to do it can be implemented in the code.
2. Selecting certain columns like: All columns or certain columns etc
3. Is there a feature of selecting columns from the user end for jasperviwer exporting to pdf.
```

Answer (score -1):

In Ireport you can do easily, open   Ireport designer and open report and the go to "report inspector"
there you can change the height and width of the report.